# C# WebMethod - Send and receive same custom object as parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, json, webmethod

mycode:

object:

```
public class Person
{

    private string _Nome;
    private DateTime _Nascimento;

    public string Nome { get { return _Nome; } }
    public DateTime Nascimento { get { return _Nascimento; } }

    public Person(string Nome, DateTime Nascimento)
    {
        _Nome = Nome;
        _Nascimento = Nascimento;
    }

}
```

page (WebMethods):

```
[WebMethod]
public static Person SendPerson()
{
    return new Person("Jhon Snow", DateTime.Now);
}

[WebMethod]
public static string ReceivePerson(Person oPerson)
{
    return "OK!";
}
```

javascript:

```
var Person;
GetPerson();
SendPersonBack();
function GetPerson()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "frmVenda.aspx/SendPerson",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (RequestReturn) {
            Person = RequestReturn.d;
            console.log(Person);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    });
}
function SendPersonBack()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "frmVenda.aspx/ReceivePerson",
        data: JSON.stringify({"oPerson": Person}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (RequestReturn) {
            alert(RequestReturn.d);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

I send the object to the clientside normally, but can not receive it back to server.
Why can not receive it back if the object is the same and their properties as well.
where is the problem?

Comment: Which method is failing?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: when I send null from clientside works out well

Comment: It sounds like a Serialization issue... If you debug the server, what exception do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a constructor with no parameters , setting all properties as string and adding the set method on all properties on my custom object (Person).

```
 public class Person
    {

        private string _Nome;
        private string _Nascimento;

        public string Nome { get { return _Nome; } set { _Nome = value; } }
        public string Nascimento { get { return _Nascimento; } set { _Nascimento= value; } }

        public Person()
        {

        }

        public Person(string Nome, DateTime Nascimento)
        {
            _Nome = Nome;
            _Nascimento = Nascimento.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the very link provided by you is possible to notice the problem.

Your code: `data: JSON.stringify({"oPerson": Person}),`

Right code: data: `"{oPerson:" + JSON.stringify(Person) + "}",`

It seems to me that you're sending a bad formatted Json to the server

Also, try adding `dataType: 'json'` to your call.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an object from webService, but your content type in ajax is json! You should create data in json format in both of your methods and return a string not object:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static static SendPerson()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return TheSerializer.Serialize(new Person("Jhon Snow", DateTime.Now));
    }
```

For second method just remove content-type from ajax or replace it by :

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: when I send the object to the client side , it normally receives . The problem is being only time to send it back to the server.

Comment: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) means server response you!! so your problem is getting wrong data from server not sending datat to server!

Comment: Yes, if I get back as string or object works fine. But why failure to receive as object Person?

Comment: I said! person is an object of `dot net class`! but ajax doesn't have any info about how convert it to `JSON`. your `ajax contenttype` is `application/json; charset=utf-8` . So your returned data must be a json not an `deserialized object` from `dot net`

Comment: in this example the guy received a C # object directly from ajax json: http://aspsnippets.com/Blue/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx